# Eclipse : Specify multiple res directories like specifying multiple src directories

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to brand my application, and only few images need to be customized, the codebase is the same except few generated constants.

As aapt allows to specify many resource directories, is there any way to specify res directories in Eclipse .classpath file? Something like

```
<classpathentry kind="androidres" path="res/common" />
<classpathentry kind="androidres" path="res/brand/mybrand_a" />
```

Or is there any other mean to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using symlinks from your brand-specific dirs to the main `res/` dir?

Comment: I am using windows. Doing so would require to create a symlink for each customized image. This does not scale.

Comment: you can't mimic the same directory structure and just create a symlink for the root directory?

Comment: A work around would be copying the customized images into the res directory. This would be the last solution (on Windows) since even aapt fails to handle multiple directories. I tried `aapt package -S res -S branding/mybrand/res -M AndroidManifest.xml -A assets -J build/gen -I D:/software/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-8/android.jar` which logs tons of errors. Specifying only one  souce (-S) directory make aapt happier.

Answer (score 0):

I have no trouble making aapt use multiple resource directories. The target for building the resources in my ant build.xml contains what is shown below, and the branded resources take precedence over the non-branded ones. I don't see any way to do the equivalent for building with Eclipse, however.

```
    <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="package" />
        <arg value="-m" />
        <arg value="-J" />
        <arg path="${folder.gen}" />
        <arg value="-M" />
        <arg path="AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <arg value="-I" />
        <arg path="${android.jar}" />
        <arg value="-A" />
        <arg path="${location.assets.branded}" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg path="${location.res.branded}" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg path="${location.resource}" />
    </exec>
```